# How to encode part of URL using nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a download section on my website, for now i give my visitors the download link in this scheam:

```
https://example.com/somerandomtext/file.zip
```

I would like to encrypt the url on php level to:

```
https://example.com/encrypted_somerandomtext/file.zip
```

And decrypt to on nginx using proxy_pass.

The code i use to enrypt the `somerandomtext` part is:

```
<?php

function buildSecureLink($path, $secret)
{
    $md5 = md5(" $secret", true);
    $md5 = base64_encode($md5);
    $md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_');
    $md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5);
    return $md5;
}
$secret = 'the_secret_key_configured_in_nginx';
$path = 'SJTjYD4vJATWDsHtQLx6WsnH1aNYt2PxRL9t3hZ47X';
echo buildSecureLink($path, $secret);
?>
```

How to let nginx decrypt it and proxy part to the right url?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using nginx's included [secure link module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement a script in Lua that makes the decrypt operation.

However, a bigger issue here is that you are "encrypting" by making a hash of the actual path. Hashing is a one-way operation. You cannot calculate the original value from the hashed value.